# What's this bubbling sound I hear while engine is on?

Tags: noise, cel, elantra, dashboard

My 2014 Elantra emits some sort of bubbling/boiling sound while the engine is on. It's coming mainly from underneath the driver side (left) dashboard. Once I turn the engine off, the sound continues for about 10 seconds before stopping abruptly. The sound is audible whenever the engine is on.

There are a few rare days when that sound isn't emitted at all but recently it is constantly audible. My CEL *is* on with code P0456. Could that be creating the sound? I would upload a video of it if I could.

Edit: I have things like the AC, heated seats, etc off and the noise is still clearly audible.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Try turning your HVAC system off. I'm betting what you're hearing is your AC gurgling. It is louder in some systems than others, but usually there.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with john. likely air in coolant system.
Do a coolant burp first.

One more possibility is combustion gasses getting into coolant.  Use a block tester to find out. (Hopefully its not that!)

P0456 would Not cause this issue. That one is likely a bad vent or purge solenoid, or bad gas cap seal. Other possibilities of course, but those are the big 3 IMO.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it's one of two things.  It "could" be the air conditioner although that's usually inaudible, unless you've got your drain plug clogged and you're holding water in the dash.  A more likely scenario is your cooling system has air trapped in it.  This is quite common in newer cars because the filler is below the highest part of the engine that needs water.  Some cars have a bleeder valve to let the air out.

Comment: I still hear it when my AC isn't running. Does that matter?

Comment: no.  It can't be the AC and never could be.  I really should have said it might be the blower fan.  The noise would also happen when the heater is on.  It's almost certainly just air in your cooling system.